# android target: android: command failed with exit code enoent Meteor

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, cross-platform

I have meteor project and I try to start it on my mobile device. It starts successfully if I run project on my windows pc and I'm getting this error(error in title) when I try to start it in my linux(ubuntu) pc. Did everything from mobile tutorial on official site of meteor and still can't start a project. I saw a lot of almost the same questions but they hadn't correct answers for me.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try run your this command in your terminal:

echo $ANDROID_HOME

it should return something like this

/home/ivan133/Android/Sdk

If it returns empty string execute these commands and build again

```
export ANDROID_HOME=${HOME}/Android/Sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools
```

Next, it would be nice to add it to your ./bashrc (if you're using bash)
Just open ~/.bashrc with text editor and copy the strings to the end

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried to do these actions, but it didn't work for. It worked for me when I wrote this thing in ~/.zshrc file

Answer (score 1):

I had followed the above instructions to no avail. Realized the `/tools` folder was somehow missing from the /sdk folder. Also it's `sdk` not `Sdk` for me.

**Complete instructions:**

1. Double check where your sdk folder is. Should be something like:
   `/User/example-user/Library/Android/sdk`
2. Visit https://developer.android.com/studio?pkg=tools and download the `SDK tools package`
3. Extract the contents of that. Should result in a directory named `tools`
4. run `open /User/example-user/Library/Android/sdk`
5. Place the `tools` folder into `/sdk` (so just to be clear, it will be at `/User/example-user/Library/Android/sdk/tools`
6. You can then do the following:

   `export ANDROID_HOME=${HOME}/Android/sdk`

   `export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools`

   `export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools`
7. `meteor remove-platform android`
8. `meteor add-platform android`

Answer (score 1):

To check the environment variables first

> env

If env variable not available means open or create .zprofile or .zshrc file in your HOME folder.

```
touch ~/.zprofile; open ~/.zprofile
or 
touch ~/.zshrc; open ~/.zshrc
```

Added these lines

```
export ANDROID_HOME=${HOME}/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=${HOME}/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools
```

After added that variable and run this below comment

```
source ~/.zprofile
or 
source ~/.zshrc
```

and it started to work

Now again to verify to type comment line

```
env
```

Check the env variable availability

Answer (score 0):

I added these lines

```
export ANDROID_HOME=${HOME}/Android/Sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools
```

to *~/.zshrc* file
and it started to work